# Graph of elevation from coordinations

Tags: here-api

I want ask you to one thing about interactive map and geo service. I need to get altitude from my coordinations points and build graph of elevation.
In google maps it looks like this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

I didn't found any example for this. How can I solve this problematic?

Thank you very much.
Best regards Petr Tomasek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a similar elevation graph via the HERE RoutingService JS API by specifying the value of `returnelevation` of the `routeRequestParams` to `true` like in this snippet:

```
var router = platform.getRoutingService();
var routeRequestParams = {
  mode: 'fastest;car',
  representation: 'display',
  waypoint0: '{lat, lng}', // Start of route
  waypoint1: '{lat, lng}', // End of route
  returnelevation: true
};
var onResult = function(result) {
  var route = result.response.route[0];
  /* Now, altitudes are the third values of the each shape point.
     Note: Shape points returned as strings.  */
  var elevation_list = route.shape.map(x => parseFloat(x.split(",")[2]));
  /* Now you can use the elevation_list as input data to 
     draw your elevation graph with any graph tool 
  */
};
var onError = function(error) {
  console.log(error);
};

router.calculateRoute(
  routeRequestParams,
  onResult,
  onError
);
```

With the elevation values you can draw your elevation graph with any JS graph library.
Checkout the routing API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/routing.html